# Get original filename from MultipartFileData in c#

Tags: c#, forms, file, post, upload

I have a POST request for file upload with a body similar to this one:

```
-----------------------------88481896131794
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Content
-----------------------------88481896131794
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="text"

asdf
-----------------------------88481896131794
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

asdf@gmail.com
```

On Visual Studio 2015, I handle the request like this:

```
string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

And I get the file name using this code:

```
foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
{
   fi.name = Path.GetFileName(file.LocalFileName);
}
```

With this method I get a totally different name `BodyPart_408513e3-60d8-42f5-bdf3-8df9742f833f` and the name I need is the original one `test.txt`

Any idea on how can I get it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below instead of `file.LocalFileName`

```
file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
```

Answer (score 3):

the `file.LocalFileName` takes the local file that was generated when saving the data from the POST request. To pull the actual filename of the file sent via the POST you have to use: `file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName`

```
foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
{
   fi.name = Path.GetFileName(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
}
```

Comment: I get an ArgumentException with that! If I use only `file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` I get "test.txt", and with a string replace I delete the quotes getting the result I need.

Comment: Cool. I will update the answer to match that :) Glad you have the result